# How can I speed up simplejson in Python?

Tags: python, simplejson

[simplejson](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson) is slow. I wish it to be fast. How might I achieve this?

Comment: There is a module simplejson._speedups that one can tell it to use somehow.

Comment: Do you have _speedups module compiled?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to speed up json decode and encode operations in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158773/how-to-speed-up-json-decode-and-encode-operations-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

simplejson has built in speedups module writen in C.

Make sure it's compiled.

( For example, check if there is /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/simplejson-2.2.1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/simplejson/_speedups.so file )

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [cjson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-cjson).

Comment: You mean, the unmaintained, not recommended module?

Comment: From cjson website: "Please don't use cjson. It is abandoned, has numerous bugs related to character escaping and Unicode, and doesn't support many features available in other JSON libraries."

Comment: cjson remains about 30-40% faster than simplejson, which is a very unreasonable gap to expect everyone to use simplejson.

Answer (score -1):

If you can update to at least python 2.6, you can use the standard lib `json` module, which will be faster since it has some speedups.

http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

Comment: My recollection is that the standalone simplejson included speeds, while the builtin json was not guaranteed to. Is that not true?

Comment: Built in json module has speedups as well. Try doing `from _json import scanstring as c_scanstring`, if it imports then your python install has the speedups.

Comment: I just found that simplejson 2.6.2 is about twice as fast at decoding short JSON messages than Python 2.7.4's `json` module. Both have compiled bits.