# The best way to store a python list to a database?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, pyramid

What would be the best way of storing a python list of numbers (such as [4, 7, 10, 39, 91]) to a database? I am using the Pyramid framework with SQLAlchemy to communicate to a database.

Thanks!

Comment: That's sure vague.  There are an indefinite number of ways of storing a list in a database.  Without some more requirements, it's hard to pick one.

Comment: Tell us about what you mean by best.

Comment: I will literally take any suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well conceptually you can store a list as a bunch of rows in a table using a one-to-many relation, or you can focus on how to store a list in a particular database backend. For example postgres can store an array in a particular cell using the sqlalchemy.dialects.postgres.ARRAY data type which can serialize a python array into a postgres array column.

Answer (score 22):

You can use [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) to save your arrays in db as stings:

```
In [1]: import json

In [2]: json.dumps([1, 2, 3])
Out[2]: '[1, 2, 3]'

In [3]: json.loads(json.dumps([1, 2, 3]))
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3]
```

also consider using [cjson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-cjson) for better performances and [anyjson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/anyjson) for nice fallbacks.

Comment: `cjson` looks interesting.  I didn't realize JSON performance was something to be concerned with, but I see a bunch of benchmarking info of different JSON python libs.  [Here's](https://github.com/rtyler/py-yajl/blob/master/compare.py) a nice comparison script I found from [another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706101/python-json-decoding-performance).

Comment: is the performance of cjson still better than the one of json?

Answer (score 0):

Use string(Varchar).
From Zen of Python: "Simple is better than complex."

Answer (score 0):

sqlalchemy.types.PickleType can store list