# Escaping quotes for MySQL in python

Tags: python, mysql

Following the advice on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222381/the-best-way-to-store-a-python-list-to-a-database), I am storing my `list` as `string` type in `MySQL database`, but, I'm facing this error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'foo_bar" but I can\\\'t bar.\', u\'high\', 0]]")\' at line 1')
```

on some list entries like this one:

```
var1 = 'Name'
var2 = 'Surname'
var3 = 15
var4 = [u'The Meter', [[u'Black', u'foo foo bar bar "foo_bar" but I can\'t bar', u'high', 0]]]
```

I figured that's because there's a double quote at the beginning of `foo_bar` and I am using the following code to make entries in the database:

```
SQL = 'INSERT INTO test_table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES ("{}", "{}", "{}", "{}")'.format(var1, var2, var3, var4)
cursor.execute(SQL)
```

And the double quotes are not being escaped.
If i remove the double quotes from: 
 **`("{}", "{}", "{}", "{}")`**, I get the same error,
I tried using a different string formatting, (using `%s`) but that didn't work either.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do *not* use string formatting to interpolate SQL values. Use SQL parameters:

```
SQL = 'INSERT INTO test_table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)'
cursor.execute(SQL, (var1, var2, var3, var4))
```

Here the `%s` are SQL parameters; the database then takes care of escaping the values (passed in as the 2nd argument to `cursor.execute) for you.

Exactly what syntax you need to use depends on your database adapter; some use `%s`, others use `?` for the placeholders.

You can't otherwise use Python containers, like a list, for these parameters. You'd have to serialise that to a string format first; you could use JSON for that, but then you'd also have to remember to decode the JSON into a Python string again when you query the database. That's what the answers to the other question tried to convey.

For example, if `var4` is the list, you could use:

```
cursor.execute(SQL, (var1, var2, var3, json.dumps(var4)))
```

Comment: Now I am getting this error: `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting` :|

Comment: @Azazelroman: did you check your database adapter documentation? Yours probably expected `%s` for the placeholders.

Comment: @martijin Oh, but as i said in the question, i got the same error while using `%s`:
`mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MyS                                                                       QL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 1")`

Comment: @Azazelroman: you didn't use them as SQL parameters then. I've swapped out the `?` placeholders with `%s` placeholders to illustrate.

Comment: @Azazelroman: where in my answer does the SQL contain double `))` parentheses? You are not executing the same code I posted. :-)

Comment: I apologize, i wasn't able to comprehend your last comment,
here's what i did
`QUERY = 'INSERT INTO test_table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)'`
`cursor.execute(QUERY, (var1, var2, var3, var4))`
And i would like to point out again that `var4` is a list which contains `", '` inside it, which i guess is creating chaos?

Comment: Can you update your question to show exactly what each `var*` contains? You can't use a list or other container as one of those values.

Comment: If `var4 = u'foo foo bar bar "foo_bar" but I can\'t bar'`, then that's no problem, that's not a container, that's a string, and it'll be escaped properly.

Comment: I implemented your updated answer. Thanks for the update. I was unable to phrase my question properly. But now i am getting this error:
`_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s, %s, %s, %s)' at line 1")`

Comment: @Azazelroman: can you create a pastie or similar with the code that produces that error? It looks as if you are calling `cursor.execute()` without parameters, thus leaving the placeholders unchanged for MySQL to interpret as SQL code..

Comment: I am getting 'ValueError: Could not process parameters' and using python 3. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @AgnelVishal sorry, without *all* of the info I asked for, I really can’t help you.

Comment: 'sql=INSERT INTO test (text) VALUES (%s);
cursor.execute(sql, (name))' is the statement and I am using mariadb.@Martijn Pieters

Comment: `(name)` is not a single-element tuple. It’s just a grouped expression. You need to add a comma: `(name,)`, or use a list: `[name]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL = 'INSERT INTO test_table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES ("{!a}", "{!a}", "{!a}", "{!a}")'.format(var1, var2, var3, str(var4))
cursor.execute(SQL)
```

`{!a}` applies `ascii()` and hence escapes non-ASCII characters like quotes and even emoticons.

Check out [Python3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)