# What is faster - Loading a pickled dictionary object or Loading a JSON file - to a dictionary?

Tags: python, json, pickle, simplejson

What is faster:

(A) 'Unpickling' (Loading) a pickled dictionary object, using `pickle.load()`

or

(B) Loading a JSON file to a dictionary using `simplejson.load()`

Assuming: The pickled object file exists already in case A, 
and that the JSON file exists already in case B.

Comment: Why ask random strangers on the Internet? Measure yourself!

Comment: It will actually depend on the content types, length, and overall size... Also while you're at it, you might also want to try cPickle and cjson (the latter is for 2.x.x, cjson is not available for 3.x.x) in your time trials.

Comment: In addition to what @Nisan.H said, there are also third party (i.e. on PyPI) JSON libraries which claim to be significantly faster.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The speed actually depends on the data, it's content and size.

But, anyway, let's take an example json data and see what is faster (Ubuntu 12.04, python 2.7.3) :

- [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)
- [cPickle](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/lib/module-cPickle.html)
- [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)
- [simplejson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/)
- [ujson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson)
- [yajl](https://github.com/rtyler/py-yajl/)

Giving this json structure dumped into `test.json` and `test.pickle` files:

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Testing script:

```
import timeit

import pickle
import cPickle

import json
import simplejson
import ujson
import yajl


def load_pickle(f):
    return pickle.load(f)


def load_cpickle(f):
    return cPickle.load(f)


def load_json(f):
    return json.load(f)


def load_simplejson(f):
    return simplejson.load(f)


def load_ujson(f):
    return ujson.load(f)


def load_yajl(f):
    return yajl.load(f)


print "pickle:"
print timeit.Timer('load_pickle(open("test.pickle"))', 'from __main__ import load_pickle').timeit()

print "cpickle:"
print timeit.Timer('load_cpickle(open("test.pickle"))', 'from __main__ import load_cpickle').timeit()

print "json:"
print timeit.Timer('load_json(open("test.json"))', 'from __main__ import load_json').timeit()

print "simplejson:"
print timeit.Timer('load_simplejson(open("test.json"))', 'from __main__ import load_simplejson').timeit()

print "ujson:"
print timeit.Timer('load_ujson(open("test.json"))', 'from __main__ import load_ujson').timeit()

print "yajl:"
print timeit.Timer('load_yajl(open("test.json"))', 'from __main__ import load_yajl').timeit()
```

Output:

```
pickle:
107.936687946

cpickle:
28.4231381416

json:
31.6450419426

simplejson:
20.5853149891

ujson:
16.9352178574

yajl:
18.9763481617
```

As you can see, unpickling via `pickle` is not that fast at all - `cPickle` is definetely the way to go if you choose pickling/unpickling option. `ujson` looks promising among these json parsers on this particular data.

Also, `json` and `simplejson` libraries load much faster on [pypy](http://pypy.org/) (see [Python JSON Performance](http://liangnuren.wordpress.com/2012/08/13/python-json-performance/)).

See also:

- [Python JSON decoding performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706101/python-json-decoding-performance)
- [Pickle or json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259270/pickle-or-json)
- [Pickle vs JSON — Which is Faster?](http://kovshenin.com/2010/pickle-vs-json-which-is-faster/)

It's important to note that the results may differ on your particular system, on other type and size of data.

Comment: Wow, pretty illustrative answer.  I didn't even know simplejson is fater than json. Further, what could be the reason of the json way being faster? (I speculate that's because its easier to parse and convert json to dictionaries, rather than parsing some pickled string which could represent any python object.)

Comment: What time do you get when you use cpickle with your example?

Comment: Just a sec, will add `ujson` and `cPickle`.

Comment: Please see updated answer. `cPickle` and `ujson` changed the whole picture here :)

Comment: Added `yajl` to the benchmark.

Comment: @pramttl answering your question: there were a discussion and useful links here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259270/pickle-or-json. Please, check.

Comment: Repeatedly opening the same file often results in the file being cached by the disk.  Do your times change if you change the order of your tests?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski good point, but it doesn't affect the results - tested. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: FWIW, in my own testing of just `pickle` vs `json`, using `cPickle` with the highest pickle protocol was faster than using json (Python 2.7.8 on Windows 7). Complete code and the results obtained have been posted [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5508445/stackoverflow/what-is-faster-loading-a-pickled-dictionary-object-or-loading-a-json-file.txt) (since I can't post them as an answer to a closed question).