# Python parse Json with key with special character

Tags: python, marshmallow

Hello I'm using python marshmallow package to convert a json file into python objects. However the one of the keys contains special character.

```
from marshmallow import Schema

fakeJson = {"A":"33","$C":"12"}

class tempA:
    def __init__(self,
                 A = None):
        self.A = A

class tempASchema(Schema):
    model = tempA
    A = fields.Str()

result=tempASchema().load(fakeJson)
```

I'm trying to convert the element "$C" into a variable. but I don't know how to deal the special character "$".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you getting an error? what is the issue exactly?

Comment: json supports that... traceback/error please

Comment: Marshmallow is not a tool for parsing json files. `marshmallow is an ORM/ODM/framework-agnostic library for converting complex datatypes, such as objects, to and from native Python datatypes.` source: https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/

Comment: @aws_apprentice I'm not getting any error. I just want convert "$C" into a variable. But don't know how to handle "$" there.

Comment: You can't have a dollar sign in the name of a variable

Comment: @ForceBru Understand, but can I convert the "$C" value into variable named "C"?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't have an error. Trying to convert the value of "$C": "12" into a python variable, not necessarily the original name. Maybe say "C".

Answer (score -1):

Marshmallow is not a tool for parsing json files. `marshmallow is an ORM/ODM/framework-agnostic library for converting complex datatypes, such as objects, to and from native Python datatypes.` source: marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0

Use `json` python module to load JSON.

Here is an example that demonstrates how to create and load JSON strings in Python:

```
import json

# this is how you create a dict object in python
pythonDictExample = {"A":"33","$C":"12"}

# this is how to create a json string from python dict
jsonExample = json.dumps(pythonDictExample)

print("Printing json string")
print(jsonExample)

# this is how you load a json string into a python dict
loadedPythonDict = json.loads(jsonExample)

print("Printing dict (loaded json string)")
print(loadedPythonDict)
```

Comment: Thanks. What I'm trying to achieve is to convert the Json into python datatypes.

Comment: JSON is not really a datatype, it's a serialization format. If you load JSON in python you get dict.

Comment: To simplify. Dict is a python object. JSON is a string. You should check out this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169404/python-dictionary-or-json

Comment: Correct. How do you then convert the dictionary with special character into a custom object.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "custom object"? Python dict handles special characters just fine. You can create it like this: `pythonDictExample = {"A":"33","$C":"12"}` and convert it to JSON like this: `jsonStringExample = json.dumps(pythonDictExample)`

Comment: "result" in my example, is a tempASchema class.

Comment: Do you really want to use the marshmallow to serialize the dictionary? What do you want to achieve by using marshmallow?