# Reading huge number of json files in Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas

This is not about reading large JSON files, instead it's about reading large number of JSON files in the most efficient way.

**Question**

I am working with [last.fm](http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/lastfm) dataset from the [Million song dataset](http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong).
The data is available as a set of JSON-encoded text files where the keys are: track_id, artist, title, timestamp, similars and tags.

Currently I'm reading them into pandas in the following way after going through a few options as this is the fastest as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037430/pandas-reading-multiple-json-records-into-dataframe):

```
import os
import pandas as pd
try:
    import ujson as json
except ImportError:
    try:
        import simplejson as json
    except ImportError:
        import json


# Path to the dataset
path = "../lastfm_train/"

# Getting list of all json files in dataset
all_files = [os.path.join(root,file) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path) for file in files if file.endswith('.json')] 

data_list=[json.load(open(file)) for file in all_files]
df = pd.DataFrame(data_list, columns=['similars', 'track_id'])
df.set_index('track_id', inplace=True)
```

The current method reads the subset (1% of full dataset in less than a second). However, reading the full train set is too slow and takes forever (I have waited for couple of hours as well) to read and has become a bottleneck for further tasks such as shown in [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41628732/how-to-efficiently-create-a-sparse-adjacency-matrix-from-adjacency-list).

I'm also using `ujson` for speed purposes in parsing json files which can be seen evidently from [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517949/what-is-faster-loading-a-pickled-dictionary-object-or-loading-a-json-file-to)

**UPDATE 1**
Using generator comprehension instead of list comprehension.

```
data_list=(json.load(open(file)) for file in all_files)
```

Comment: It sounds like you don't have enough RAM, and it starts to use SWAP, the easiest solution would be to get more RAM.

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo Easiest maybe.. but definitely not the cheapest! :D

Comment: I already have 16Gigs of that and I think that definitely enough for reading a normal dataset like this. Is there a better way of reading so many json files ?

Comment: Reading in all the JSONs one-by-one then writing columns you want out to a CSV would be borderline trivial, take virtually no RAM, and simplify the format so Pandas, Numpy or whatever else could read it en masse in a probably more efficient manner.

Comment: I recommend you have a look at [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) as it can fit your needs well

Comment: From http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/lastfm "Because going over JSON files is inefficient, and most people will only work on similarity or tags, **we provide two SQLite databases** with the data.". Download that then `pd.read_sql('SELECT similars, track_id FROM ...', ...)`.

Comment: what is the total size of all your JSON files?

Comment: @MaxU: Total size of Jsons is 2.5 GBs.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to read and write the dataset multiple times, you could try converting `.json` files into a faster format. For example in pandas 0.20+ you could try using the `.feather` format.

Answer (score 0):

I would build an iterator on files and just `yield` the two columns you want.

Then you can instantiate a `DataFrame` with that iterator.

```
import os
import json
import pandas as pd

# Path to the dataset
path = "../lastfm_train/"

def data_iterator(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for f in files:
            if f.endswith('.json'):
                fp = os.path.join(root,f)
                with open(fp) as o:
                    data = json.load(o)
                yield {"similars" : data["similars"], "track_id": data["track_id"]}


df = pd.DataFrame(data_iterator(path))
df.set_index('track_id', inplace=True)
```

This way you only go over your files list once and you won't duplicate the data before and after passing it to `DataFrame`

Comment: Please see the update, using generator comprehension already.

Comment: Using the code I posted (with native package `json`), I loaded the full train set dataset in `104 seconds`

Comment: My code as well as your code loads the the subset(1%) in 1.04 seconds and hence, expected the full to load in something around 100s. However, on my machine your code takes 406s and my code takes 473s.

I'm using a Macbook Pro 2015 version with 16GB RAM.

What beast are you using that is scaling to the full dataset perfectly?

Comment: :-) I work on a dedicated server like this one : https://www.ovh.co.uk/dedicated_servers/details-servers-range-BIGDATA-id-2016-HG-1.xml

Comment: Seriously? I hope you're kidding.